# heroku/django/postgres django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host...SSL off

Tags: django, postgresql, ssl, heroku

I'm getting the above error at startup while trying to connect to a heroku postgres db from my django app. This is from my Mac running El Cap, 10.11.5 - seems to work fine from my laptop that is thankfully still running Yosemite. I tried upgrading everything - python 2.7.11, latest psycopg2 and latest Django. Maybe I need to bite the bullet and go for python 3? It connects just fine with heroku pg:psql! Here's the whole stack. Thanks!

```
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 163, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 175, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/da/dev/pwapp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[ip]", user "", database "[yadda]", SSL off
```

Comment: how are you configuring your database settings?